# How to write a generic expression tree for filter data in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

Hi  I Create a winform Application in c#.

I use EF5 to work with database.

and for bind data to my datagridviews i created a component from BindingSource that has a Bind() method that run this event:

```
private object bindingSourceTbl1_DataSourceBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
    {
      return(from x in dbo.Tbl1
             where x.Id == (int)comboBoxPerson.SelectedValue
             select x).Take(1000).ToList();
    }
}
```

because my database has  many large data i fetch partial of data.
and i use search for get match record. for this i created a SearchPanel component that create textboxes for filter each columns in my grid.

at now i want to send an expression tree to my event as a parameter to join to where clause like this:

```
private object bindingSourceTbl1_DataSourceBinding(object sender, EventArgs e,Expression whereClause)
{
    using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
    {
      return(from x in dbo.Tbl1
             where x.Id == (int)comboBoxPerson.SelectedValue && whereClause
             select x).Take(1000).ToList();
    }
}
```

but my expression tree builder method exists in my component code and i dont access to my DbContext in my project and just i have fieldNames in my component, also i want to write just one method for all tables.

this means i can't return like

> Expression< Func< AnyDbSet,bool>>

and i don't know how do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need just `&&`, then it's helpful to realize that `coll.Where(x => a(x) && b(x))` (where `a(x)` and `b(x)` are any boolean expressions that work with `x`) is logically the same as  `coll.Where(x => a(x)).Where(x => b(x))`. What this means is that you can rewrite your code to something like:

```
List<Tbl1Type> GetTbl1Values(Expression<Func<Tbl1Type, bool>> whereClause)
{
    using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
    {
        return dbo.Tbl1
            .Where(x => x.Id == (int)comboBoxPerson.SelectedValue)
            .Where(whereClause)
            .Take(1000).ToList();
    }
}
```

If you also needed to support `||` or more complicated combinations, you could use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

This just leaves the matter of creating the expression from a property name. You can use method of the `Expression` type for that. For example, something like:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateWhereClause<T>(
    string propertyName, object propertyValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName),
            Expression.Constant(propertyValue)),
        parameter);
}
```

Comment: thank you.
i solved my problem with your solution.
but yet i have a problem. because i need to search data with enter filter value i need to convert properties to string but Expression not supported this. for example it failed to convert decimal or double to string an my code is:

Comment: var propInfo = this.dataSourceItemsType.GetProperty(fieldsName[i], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.GetField);


                    Expression columnExpr = Expression.Property(entityParameter, propInfo);
                    if (propInfo.PropertyType != typeof(String))
                    {
                        columnExpr = Expression.Convert(columnExpr, typeof(String));
                    }


I search on this problem and i saw that this problem is a bug in expression trees.
can you help me to solved it?

Comment: @noorashegh I don't think that's a bug, `Convert` is an equivalent of casting and you can't simply cast `decimal` to `string` in C#. Instead, you could create an expression that invokes [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert).

Comment: **you are a good friend.your solutions worked for me.**
thank you very very much.
and for that bug i read it from this urls:
[link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/697908/expression-trees-no-coercion-operator-is-defined-between-types)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700401/is-this-is-an-expressiontrees-bug-2)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

your can use [dynamic linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).
here is a example:

```
var result = northwind.Products
     .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
     .OrderBy("SupplierID");
```

===

```
private object bindingSourceTbl1_DataSourceBinding(object sender, EventArgs e,Expression whereClause)
{
    using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
    {
         var q = from x in dbo.Tbl1
             where x.Id == (int)comboBoxPerson.SelectedValue && whereClause
             select x);
         q = q.Where(whereClause)// your must reference dynamic linq library.
                                 //whereClause is expression
               .Take(100);
         return q.ToList();

    }
```

}

Comment: Could you explain how exactly would you use Dynamic LINQ in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the PredicateBuilder by Joseph Albahari. You can find it at http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx.

Comment: PredicateBuilder by itself isn't enough, because it creates expression that EF won't accept.

Comment: i used it before but i don't know how to use it for my purpose.
i have many grid that i want to fill those by filtering and get new proper data from database.
and i have a one method for generate my predicate for send to bind method that exists in my component and in this method i have a string array that contains name of fields and one string array that contains filter values and also type of data like typeof(Tbl1).